# Are modular lattices shallow?

Tags: lattice-theory, universal-algebra

Let $A$ be a universal algebra with finitely many finitary operations. Write $F_n$ for the $n$-ary operations.

We define the **affine maps** on $A$ inductively: $\eta \mapsto \eta$ and $\eta \mapsto c$ where $c \in A$ are affine, and if $f \in F_n$ and $c_i \in A$ are constants, and $g$ is affine, then $\eta \mapsto f(c_1, \ldots, c_k, g(\eta), c_{k+2}, \ldots, c_n)$ is affine.

Affine maps can be thought of as syntactic objects (terms with one variable and constants), and the **depth** of an affine map is the number of times we use the inductive step in the definition, i.e. "how many layers of parenthesis surround $\eta$". On the other hand, an affine map gives a function $f : A \to A$, and two affine maps $f, g$ are **equivalent** if they define the same function.

(BTW, I've called these "affine maps" because for some universal algebras these are the affine maps, and I don't know a meaning for that term in universal algebra, but do tell if you know a more standard term for this.)

Now, we say $A$ is **$k$-shallow** if for every affine map $f$, there exists an affine map $g$ with depth at most $k$, which is equivalent to $f$.

Now let $V$ be a variety of universal algebras (so the class of universal algebras with a fixed set of operations, satisfying a fixed set of laws). We say $V$ is **$k$-shallow** if every algebra in $V$ is $k$-shallow. We say $V$ is **shallow** if it is $k$-shallow for some $k$.

Examples:

- **Groups** are a variety with operations $((x, y) \mapsto x \cdot y) \in F_2$, $(x \mapsto x^{-1}) \in F_1$ and identity $e \in F_0$, and you know the laws. This variety is $3$-shallow: the deepest type of term we need is $\eta \mapsto (x \cdot \eta^{-1}) \cdot y$.
- **Lattices** have operations $\wedge, \vee \in F_2$ and satisfy laws $x \vee y \equiv y \vee x$, $x \vee (y \vee z) \equiv (x \vee y) \vee z$, $x \vee x \equiv x$, $x \equiv x \vee (x \wedge y$, and the laws obtained by exchanging $\vee \leftrightarrow \wedge$. I know a roundabout way to prove that lattices are not shallow, but I don't have a simple direct proof.

> Pre-question. Is there a simple proof that lattices are not shallow?

(According to Wikipedia, in the free lattice on generators $x, y, z$, the elements defined inductively by $p_0 = x$ and $p_{n+1} = (x \vee (y \wedge (z \vee (x \wedge (y \vee (z \wedge p_n))))))$ are distinct; I suppose the affine maps obtained by setting $p_0 = \eta$ are not shallow, but I don't know much about these lattices.)

- **Distributive lattices** are lattices, with additional laws $x \vee (y \wedge z) \equiv (x \vee y) \wedge (x \vee z)$ and the law obtained by exchanging $\vee \leftrightarrow \wedge$. Distributive lattices are $2$-shallow, with the deepest affine maps equivalent to $\eta \mapsto (\eta \vee x) \wedge y$.

We now get to the modular lattices. These are the lattices where the projection to an interval $[a, b]$ is well-defined in the sense that $a \leq b$ (meaning $a = a \wedge b$) implies $(c \vee a) \wedge b \equiv (c \wedge b) \vee a)$ for all $c$. To make these into a variety, we can rephrase this as the law $(a \wedge b) \vee (x \wedge b) \equiv ((a \wedge b) \vee x) \wedge b$ (this is added on top of the laws of the variety of lattices).

> Question. Is the variety of modular lattices shallow?

One can ask about finite variants of these notions, i.e. bounded shallowness of finite algebras. It also interests me whether modular lattices are "finitely shallow", i.e. finite modular lattices are $k$-shallow for some fixed $k$. (Of course, any individual finite algebra is $k$-shallow for some $k$.)

(The motivation for this question is symbolic dynamical, and I don't know how this links to existing research in universal algebra. Feel free to school me on this!)

Comment: Why is not $\eta\mapsto\eta^n$ affine for groups? Surely $f(x)=x^n$ is in $F_n$ for groups, right?

Comment: No. In the variety of groups, we have exactly three operations: $|F_2| = |F_1| = |F_0| = 1$, namely we have multiplication, inversion and taking the identity element. I agree what you write is a term, but it is neither an operation nor an affine map. Note that shallowness could in principle depend on the choice of operations. But I think mine is the most standard way to present groups, if you want them to form a universal algebraic variety.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Terminology.**

If $f$ is a fundamental operation of an algebra $A$, then a polynomial of the form $f(c_1,\ldots,c_k,x,c_{k+2},\ldots,c_n)$ is often called a 'basic translation' or a '$1$-translation' of $A$. A composition of $k$  $1$-translations is called a $k$-translation and a 'translation' is a $k$-translation for some $k$. This terminology can be found in Definition 3.1 of

Kirby A. Baker
Finite equational bases for finite algebras in a congruence-distributive equational class
Advances in Mathematics 24, 207-243, (1977)

Baker credits the terminology to

A. I. Mal'cev
On the general theory of algebraic systems
Math. Sb. (N.S.) 35 (77) (1954)

'Translations' are not exactly the same as 'affine maps' since the identity function and the constant functions are not guaranteed to be translations, but if you expand the language trivially to include a new basic operation $t(x,y)$ satisfying $t(x,y) = x$ then you can obtain the identity and every constant as a $1$-translation in the new language.

**Math.**

The variety of modular lattices is not shallow. To see this, consider the sequence $L_1, L_2, L_3, \ldots$ of (simple) modular lattices constructed according to this pattern:

[image: L7]

There is an $8$-translation $t(x)$ such that $t(a)=c$ and $t(b)=d$, namely
$t(x)=(((((((x\vee u_1)\wedge u_2)\vee u_3)\wedge u_4)\vee u_5)\wedge u_6)\vee u_7)\wedge c$. This translation witnesses the fact that the pair $(c,d)$ belongs to the congruence generated by the pair $(a,b)$.

There is no $(\leq 6)$-translation that maps $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ for the following reasons. Assume that $g(x)$ is any $(\leq 6)$-translation that maps $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$. Each $1$-translation is equivalent to one of the form $x\vee c$ or $x\wedge c$, hence involves only one constant as a parameter. Since $g(x)$ is a $(\leq 6)$-translation, it can involve at most $6$ of the $u$'s as parameters. Since there are $7$ $u$'s in $L_7$, some $u_i$ is not a constant parameter in $g(x)$. Each $u_i$ is doubly irreducible in $L_7$, so $L_7-\{u_i\}$ is a (modular) sublattice of $L_7$. Now, $g(x)$ restricts to a unary polynomial function of $L_7-\{u_i\}$ which is assumed to satisfy $g(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$. This forces $(c,d)$ to be in the congruence generated by $(a,b)$ in the sublattice $L_7-\{u_i\}$.
But it is easy to see that $(c,d)$ is NOT in the congruence generated by $(a,b)$ in the sublattice $L_7-\{u_i\}$.

Now let $7$ go to infinity. The same argument shows that for any odd $n$, $L_n$ will have an $(n+1)$-translation that maps $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$, but no $(\leq(n-1))$-translation that does this.

---

**Response to comments.**

1. **I couldn't find a simple argument that this is modular**

To check that a finite lattice is modular, it suffices to check that each of its 'small' intervals is modular. Let me define 'smallness' and sketch a path one could take to prove the criterion of the preceding sentence, and then say how the criterion applies to $L_n$.

Write $x\prec y$ to mean that $x < y$ and there is no $z$ with $x<z<y$.
When $x\prec y$, call $x$ a lower cover of $y$ and $y$ an upper cover of $x$ or say that $x$ is covered by $y$ or $y$ covers $x$. Now, when $L$ is a finite lattice, call an interval $I\subseteq L$ 'small' if $I=[x\wedge y, x\vee y]$ where both $x$ and $y$ cover $x\wedge y$ or both are covered by $x\vee y$. I claim that a finite lattice is modular iff all of its small intervals are modular.

To prove that this criterion for modularity is correct for finite lattices, you could follow these steps.

Show that a finite lattice is modular iff it is both upper semimodular [$((x\wedge y)\prec x)\to (y\prec (x\vee y))$]
and lower semimodular [$(y\prec (x\vee y))\to ((x\wedge y)\prec x)$].

Show that a finite lattice is upper semimodular iff whenever both $x$ and $y$ cover $x\wedge y$, then both $x$ and $y$ are covered by $x\vee y$. The dual claim holds for lower semimodularity.

Now prove the criterion: a finite lattice $L$ is modular iff 
whenever $I=[x\wedge y,x\vee y]$ is an interval where both $x$ and $y$ cover $x\wedge y$ or both $x$ and $y$ are covered by $x\vee y$, then $I$ is modular.

To see how the criterion applies to $L_n$, let $u_i^+$ denote the unique upper cover of $u_i$ in $L_n$ and let $u_i^-$ denote the unique lower over of $u_i$ in $L_n$. Convince yourself that the interval $[u_i^-,u_i^+]$ is small and isomorphic to $M_3$, hence is a small modular interval. Then convince yourself that all other small intervals are isomorphic to $M_2$, which is modular. Since all small intervals are modular, $L_n$ is modular.

**2. I also don't have a clear argument for that thing that's easy to see**

This is referring to my claim that in the sublattice $L_n-\{u_i\}$ the pair $(c,d)$ is not in the congruence generated by the pair $(a,b)$. To prove this, it suffices to exhibit some congruence $\theta$ on $L_n-\{u_i\}$ that contains $(a,b)$ and does not contain $(c,d)$, so let me describe such a $\theta$. I will explain this for the case where $u_i$ has even subscript, but you can modify the argument to handle the case where $u_i$ has odd subscript.

When $i$ is even, the sublattice $L_n-\{u_i\}$ has a unique lattice retraction $\rho$ which has image equal to the interval $[u_i^+\wedge c, u_i^+\vee c]$ and which maps all of the elements in the set $\{a, b, u_1,\ldots,u_{i-1}\}$ to the element $u_i^+$. Let $\theta$ be the kernel of $\rho$. Since $\rho(a)=\rho(b)=u_i^+$, $(a,b)\in\theta$. Since $c$ and $d$ are distinct elements of $\textrm{im}(\rho)$ and $\rho^2=\rho$, we have $(c,d)\notin\theta$.

(To modify this for odd subscripts I would use $u_i^-$ in place of $u_i^+$ in the above argument.)

Comment: Thanks! This question is about 10 years old (for me); the last 5 or so I have resisted asking it here, but finally caved in :)

Comment: Your answer looks convincing. I couldn't find a simple argument that this is modular, but I did a careless case analysis to check that there are no obvious $N_5$s. I also don't have a clear argument for that thing that's easy to see, but I do agree it is easy to see, since you get a kind of decomposition into two rectangles.

Comment: Ok, I didn't do the exercise about modular lattices in full detail yet, but I assume it's standard, and then the check is indeed very quick. The congruence thing is now also clear. Much appreciated!

Comment: Concerning modularity of the lattice, it is also easy to represent it as a lattice of linear spaces. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3r0q.jpg) the lattice is embedded in the lattice of subspaces of $\mathbb R^8$, written as $2\times4$ matrices. I hope the notation is not too cryptic: for example, $\begin{smallmatrix}R&R&&0\\&&\smash{\|}&\\0&0&&R\end{smallmatrix}$ denotes the space $\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a_0&a_1&a_2&a_3\\ b_0&b_1&b_2&b_3\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in\mathbb R^{2\times4}:a_3=b_0=b_1=0,a_2=b_2\right\}$. (For the lower row of $u_i$s, the equality sign is diagonal.)

Comment: Thanks @EmilJeřábek! The notation is not too cryptic, and looks correct. I am specifically interested in representing this as an internal modular lattice in the category of sofic shifts on the integers. I now have a hunch that your comment solves this problem, just by interpreting the symbols suitably, which would be cool. It's a problem I never worked on very hard, because I didn't know enough about modular lattices to really get started, but nevertheless it's been on my mind for a decade (we asked this question in 2012 https://villesalo.com/article/OSSwAS.pdf ).

Comment: https://symbolicdynamicsandotherthings.wordpress.com/2023/07/05/a-non-cellwiseable-modular-lattice/ directly interpreted, your comment gives that there is a "non-cellwiseable modular subshift of finite type". For now it remains open whether it can be made mixing, which would be of additional interest.

Comment: That’s great! I wish I knew something about shift dynamics.